# Compare two definition of $Rf_!$ (derived pushforward with proper support)

Tags: algebraic-geometry, derived-functors, etale-cohomology, derived-categories

I'm talking about etale sheaves.
For a morphism $f:X\to Y$ of schemes, there are two definition of $Rf_!:D(X)\to D(Y)$.

The usual derived functor:
$\forall\mathcal{F}\in Sh(X)$, let $f_!\mathcal{F}$ be the sheaf associated to the presheaf $U\mapsto\{s\in\Gamma(U\times_YX,\mathcal{F}):\operatorname{Supp}s$ is proper over $U\}$
$f_!:Sh(X)\to Sh(Y)$ is left exact, and we can consider its right derived functor $Rf_!$ (?)

Via compactification:
Under some finiteness assumptions, we can consider "compactifiable" morphisms
If $f:X\to Y$ is compactifiable (over $S$), let $X\overset{i}\hookrightarrow\bar{X}\overset{\bar{f}}{\to}Y$ be a compactification
i.e. $i:X\hookrightarrow\bar{X}$ open immersion, $\bar{f}:\bar{X}\to Y$ proper.
We can set $Rf_!=R\bar{f}_*i_!$, which make sense since extension by zero ($i_!$) is exact
(See for example Stack Project section 62.9)

In p357 of $\textit{Etale Cohomology Theory}$ of Lei Fu, he said that $Rf_!$ defined via compactification needn't be the derived functor of $f_!$. I didn't find further discussion about the relation between the two definition.

It seems that if the usual derived functor $Rf_!$ exists, $f=\bar{f}\circ i$, then $R\bar{f}_*\circ i_!\simeq R\bar{f}_!\circ Ri_!\simeq Rf_!$.
Is this a correct argument?

Comment: No, in general the derived functor of $f_!$ does not behave well and does not give what is intended. And you can't say that the derived functor of $\overline{f}_*\circ i_!$ will be $R\overline{f}_*\circ Ri_!$. The problem is that $i_!$ does not send an injective sheaf to an acyclic sheaf for $\overline{f}_*$. In the context of etale cohomology, the notation $Rf_!$ is used for $R\overline{f}_*\circ i_!$ and is actually not a derived functor.

Comment: Oh, I see. Thank you!